# Drop-down menu not showing with autocomplete.js library

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete

I'm using a JS library and it was actually working for a few moments, but then later it stopped showing the drop-down menu after I would type something in. You're supposed to be able to type something and the default drop-down menu of food and drinks is supposed to show up, but now it is not. So I know something is wrong.

Here is the section of HTML I attached it to.

```
<!-- MESSAGE USERS -->
            <section class="message-users">
                <h2>Message User</h2>
                <input type="search" id="autoComplete">
                <!-- <textarea rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Message for User"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">    -->
            </section>
```

If you go to my fiddle and scroll-down you'll see the search bar and how it doesn't show the placeholder either, which is weird as well.

Could I get any suggestions? Its quite easy to use, but for some reason its acting glitchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is currently not working in your fiddle is because the API key is not defined. In line 337:

```
const source = await fetch(`https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${token}&q=${query}`);
```

The variable `token` seems to be not defined and therefore an error is thrown when the autocomplete should be initialized:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: token is not defined
    at Object.src ((index):702)
    at Object.src (autoComplete.min.js:1)
    at t.value (autoComplete.min.js:1)
    at new t (autoComplete.min.js:1)
    at window.onload ((index):698)
```

So I assume defining `token` before initializing the autocomplete should fix it. Since the initialization didn't work, also the placeholder is not displayed.

Since I don't have a subscription in food2fork.com I cannot test it. Therefore I would also generally suggest posting fiddles that could be used by everybody without signing up for a third part service.

Comment: There are lots of APIs that need a key, but are for free. You can find some of them here: https://public-apis.xyz/

Also, for more flexibility and better documentation, have a look at the jQuery solution for autocomplete: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/